# autocomplete on dynamic fields - show user sugestions from mysql for input data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working to a code for adding products to a database.
In my form I have dynamic fields to save more products at a time.
I found on forum a JS script that create sugestions for user input data, and the problem is related to JS code.
All my data that a user searches for is stored in mysql.

EDIT: I changed a part of code and now is working better, but have new bug.
If I add more field at a time, sugestion list is displayed only to last input added, no matter what field you use for search (and first field can't search).
If I search one field at a time, and then add new one and search again, it's ok.
What is wrong?

My new **HTML**:

```
                    <!--tabel add rows-->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="mobilier_fields"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 nopadding">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod_mobilier" name="cod_mobilier[]">
                                <div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"  onclick="mobilier_fields();"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    //script for add dynamic fields
var room = 1;
function mobilier_fields() {
    room++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('mobilier_fields')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
    var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="col-sm-5 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod_mobilier'+ room +'" name="cod_mobilier[]"><div id="suggesstion-box'+ room +'"></div></div></div><div class="col-sm-2 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_education_fields('+ room +');"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';

    objTo.appendChild(divtest)

    autoComplete();

}
function remove_education_fields(rid) {
    $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
}



//script for sugestions
function autoComplete() {
    $("#cod_mobilier"+room).keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "autocomplete.php",
        data:'keyword_autocomplete='+$(this).val(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#cod_mobilier"+room).css("background","#FFF url(images/LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#suggesstion-box"+room).show();
            $("#suggesstion-box"+room).html(data);
            $("#cod_mobilier"+room).css("background","#FFF");
        }
        });
    });
}


function selectprodus(val) {
$("#cod_mobilier"+room).val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box"+room).hide();
}

$("#cod_mobilier"+room).keyup(function(){
    autoComplete();
});
```

autocomplete.php:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["keyword_autocomplete"])) {
$query ="SELECT * FROM tbl_nomenclator WHERE cod_produs like '%" . $_POST["keyword_autocomplete"] . "%' OR descriere_produs like '%" . $_POST["keyword_autocomplete"] . "%' ORDER BY descriere_produs LIMIT 0,10";
$result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
if(!empty($result)) {
?>
<ul id="nomenclator-list">
<?php
foreach($result as $rezultat) {
?>
<li onClick="selectprodus('<?php echo $rezultat["cod_produs"]; ?>');"><?php echo $rezultat["cod_produs"]; ?> - <?php echo $rezultat["descriere_produs"]; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } } ?>
```

[new image for exemplification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YhRq.png)

Comment: Provide the code for more than one input field. Probably you are mixing field IDs.

Comment: Just warning you that you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Try to see what happens if you enter a quote symbol ( for example: ' ) at the autocomplete field. This way, a stranger could read your entire database.

Comment: i added external .js file. that work fine. i dont care about sql injection now. this app is only for internal use.after i make it work correctly, i will do the security

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the #search-box element in your page via JS. You must attach the keyup event to the new input field each time you create it.

Note: 
1. The code that attaches the keyup event runs only once at start-up of your page (i.e. $(document).ready(...);.
2. Attach the keyup event to the new input element.
3. You are attaching the keyup event to the element by ID. It is always recommended that we should have a unique ID for elements. #search-box always attaches the "keyup" event to the first element that matching the id (i.e. search-box).

Comment: thanks for info! I made few changes, but still not work properly. each field generate result, but the list is only displayed to last field added.

Comment: Could you check whether the ID "cod_mobilier"+room is set to the dynamic input field properly each time you create it?

Comment: Can you check the value of the "room" variable in the "success" event handler? I guess this is actually causing your logic to display the suggestion box next to the lastly added input field..

Comment: Super!!! Here is one problem. ID  "#suggesstion-box"+room" value, for each field(except first - not work if i add more fields) is the id of last field added. How can i set those ID's(#suggesstion-box and #cod_mobilie) to dynamic for autocomplete JS script? I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Afther multiple testing scenario a figured out where is the problem: As you said, "room" var is incrementing when I create multiple inputs and remain with value of last field(for four fileds, var room is 4). Analizing my code, i saw that each field has a var "rid", unique for each field from function witch remove fields. How can to pass this rid var for replace room var? If i replace room in autocomplete function, rid var value is "unknown".Thanks.